# html checkbox mapping with ms access yes/no or true/false using php

Tags: php, ms-access

I have a problem with php+ms access, I am handeling successfully all the insert udate delete and search query with php+ms access, but I am having some problem for mapping checkboxes with ms access yes/no or true/false to save my checkboxs in ms access.

Comment: And those problems are?

Comment: MS Access uses -1 (yes/true/etc), 0 (no/false/etc)